# PHP redirect if url contains specific string

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

I have a document called `content.php`, who server the content list published from two different categories.

So in both cases, catgory_1 list and _category_2 list is server by content.php

mysite.com/category_1/post/

mysite.com/category_2/post/

So, I need to redirect the user to a different page depending on catgory_? list, but without affecting the post inside that category.

Resume :

if you visit mysite.com/category_1/post/  or mysite.com/category_2/post/  ( you get the post)

But :

if you visit mysite.com/category_1/ (you get redirected to page 1)
if you visit mysite.com/category_2/ (you get redirected to page 2)

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this.
First get your url path with `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"`].
Then get all after `category_`, and if all after category is number then redirect.

```
$uri = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
$getCategory = substr($uri, strpos($uri, "category_")+9);
$getCategory = str_replace("/", "", $getCategory);

if (is_numeric($getCategory)) {
    header('Location: http://www.example.com/1');
}
else{
    header('Location: http://www.example.com/2');
}
```